# How to import python file into another python file so that it works in Docker?

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-module

When I run my app.py file I can access it on localhost and it works.

After running (and having no issues): `docker build -t flask-container .`

When I run: `docker run -p 5000:5000 flask-container`

I get: `from helpers import apology, login_required, usd`

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'helpers'`

In app.py I have: `from helpers import apology, login_required, usd`

I have tried putting in an empty `__init__.py` folder in the main folder, still doesn't work.

Question: How do I fix the Module Not Found Error when trying to run docker?

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8-alpine

# By default, listen on port 5000
EXPOSE 5000/tcp

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the dependencies file to the working directory
COPY requirements.txt .

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the content of the local src directory to the working directory
COPY app.py .

# Specify the command to run on container start
CMD [ "python", "./app.py" ]
```

requirements.txt

```
flask===2.1.0
flask_session
```

Python Version: 3.10.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please copy the helpers.py as well into the working directory.

```
COPY helpers.py .
```

OR

```
ADD . /app 
#This will add all files in the current local dir to /app
```

Comment: A `.dockerignore` for the latter is also helpful.

Comment: COPY helpers.py .

Worked, thanks!